# LoRaWAN OTAA TTN Timedout with Gateway capturing the message

Tags: lora, lorawan, zephyr-rtos

I try to set up an end node in LoRaWAN.
I use the board b_l072z_lrwan1 from ST Microelectronics with Zephyr OS.
I use PlatformIO on VSCode.

I use the code available on GitHub at https://github.com/fcgdam/zLorawan_Node.

Here is what I see on my gateway (all EUIs will be changed) :

```
{
  "name": "gs.up.receive",
  "time": "2021-10-26T12:54:26.556184636Z",
  "identifiers": [
    {
      "gateway_ids": {
        "gateway_id": "bzm-testing-gateway"
      }
    },
    {
      "gateway_ids": {
        "gateway_id": "bzm-testing-gateway",
        "eui": "B827EBFFFE6F34C2"
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/ttn.lorawan.v3.UplinkMessage",
    "raw_payload": "ACIiIiIRERERcLPVftAEdD2GalaJt3Y=",
    "payload": {
      "m_hdr": {},
      "mic": "Vom3dg==",
      "join_request_payload": {
        "join_eui": "1111111122222222",
        "dev_eui": "3D7404D07ED5B370",
        "dev_nonce": "6A86"
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "data_rate": {
        "lora": {
          "bandwidth": 125000,
          "spreading_factor": 12
        }
      },
      "coding_rate": "4/5",
      "frequency": "868500000",
      "timestamp": 1014604052,
      "time": "2021-10-26T12:54:26.535592Z"
    },
    "rx_metadata": [
      {
        "gateway_ids": {
          "gateway_id": "bzm-testing-gateway",
          "eui": "B827EBFFFE6F34C2"
        },
        "time": "2021-10-26T12:54:26.535592Z",
        "timestamp": 1014604052,
        "rssi": -45,
        "channel_rssi": -45,
        "snr": 9.8,
        "uplink_token": "CiEKHwoTYnptLXRlc3RpbmctZ2F0ZXdheRIIuCfr//5vNMIQlMLm4wMaDAiC9d+LBhCnrZWIAiCg7PTYwx0=",
        "channel_index": 2
      }
    ],
    "received_at": "2021-10-26T12:54:26.553997991Z",
    "correlation_ids": [
      "gs:conn:01FJY9PGVXJ4SE6B1SF1KDCYR4",
      "gs:uplink:01FJYAN3FVJJSC368C2PHTXN93"
    ]
  },
  "correlation_ids": [
    "gs:conn:01FJY9PGVXJ4SE6B1SF1KDCYR4",
    "gs:uplink:01FJYAN3FVJJSC368C2PHTXN93"
  ],
  "origin": "ip-10-100-5-46.eu-west-1.compute.internal",
  "context": {
    "tenant-id": "CgN0dG4="
  },
  "visibility": {
    "rights": [
      "RIGHT_GATEWAY_TRAFFIC_READ",
      "RIGHT_GATEWAY_TRAFFIC_READ"
    ]
  },
  "unique_id": "01FJYAN3FWYZ8BTA8HKB2VYB2V"
}
```

For me this means the the gateway receive a good request. Here is my configuration on ZephyrOS.

```
#define LORAWAN_DEV_EUI         { 0x3D, 0x74, 0x04, 0xD0, 0x7E, 0xD5, 0xB3, 0x70 }    // LSB Format!
#define LORAWAN_JOIN_EUI        { 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22, 0x22 } 
#define LORAWAN_APP_KEY         { 0x33, 0xE6, 0xF7, 0xF7, 0x5B, 0x46, 0xD2, 0xDC, 0x7F, 0xC4, 0x7C, 0x5F, 0x94, 0x56, 0x06, 0x43 }
```

My request times out with errno -116 which is ETIMEOUT

Here is my configuration of the device in TTN:
[image: My device description]

Do you have any clue of why my request timedout?

Answer (score 1):

I've written the DEV_EUI in LSB However, TTN seems to get it in MSB, it worked when I inverted the order of the bytes.